# MS vb 2008 richtectbox1.text and display in Words underlined

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I have a richtextbox that accept user input. when the 'cetak' (print) button are clicked then the input will go to Ms Words.

I want to display the input in Words as the input fontstyle will change to underline.

for example user input : Jessica
output at words : Jessica (with underline)

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Dim ps As New PageSettings
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph

    'Start Word and open the document template.
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = False
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
    oDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientPortrait
    Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    rng.Font.Size = 10
    oDoc.Paragraphs.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.ToUpper

    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlack
    oPara1.Range.Text = "Try: " & RichTextBox1.Text
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc.PrintPreview()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: @utility i already edit my post. i include the coding. i try to underline the input.  i use this code : oPara1.Range.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle. however this code underline the whole paragraph. i just want a certain part only

Comment: what is your output right now ?..so you need underlined word as output in word?

Comment: @utility yes. underline the output in word. if i input jessica then the output :        Try: Jessica. if i put this coding oPara1.Range.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle the whole paragraph are underline including 'Try: '. i want the input only to be underline

Answer (score 0):

From your comment :

> if i put this coding oPara1.Range.Font.Underline =
>   Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle the whole paragraph are underline
>   including 'Try: '. i want the input only to be underline

Yes text will be underlined because you are setting paragraph as  "Try: " and RichTextBox1 content

Your code :

```
oPara1.Range.Text = "Try: " & RichTextBox1.Text
```

So in order to accomplish your goal , ie. :

To underline the content in richtextbox with use the code below and then export to word:

```
 RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Font(RichTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
```

and export the same to word application.

Comment: i try it. but nothing happen. i just put your code try to run it. and nothing happen. why is that?

Comment: first add text..then select the content or word..then click the button with code behind for underline,then you can export that

Comment: i tried. new problem arise. how can i export the underline text in richtextbox to words without change the format? the text in richtextbox are underline now (thx to your code) but when i click the print button, it will export it into words but the format changed. no more underline. why?